# How to reload ng-include after route change in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a sidebar which I hide on the login page, but show on other pages.

The content of the sidebar depends on the user logged in. After the user logs in I want to refresh the sidebar which is included as `ng-include`.

```
<div ><ng-include src="'_sidebar.html'" class="page-sidebar-wrapper"></ng-include></div>

<div><ng-view></ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

`<ng-include src="navUrl" class="page-sidebar-wrapper"></ng-include>`

I attached `navUrl` to `$rootScope` and on route change from login page:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function($event, next, current) { 

    $rootScope.navUrl = "_sidebar.html";

 });
```